# Java - Alternative to PriorityQueue that keeps duplicate insertion order

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I have a problem where I need a data structure that let's me store a bunch of order objects (has price and quantity) in sorted order so that I can easily retrieve the one with the lowest price. The only operations I need are 'insert' and 'retrieve smallest' which makes a priority queue seems like a great choice, but the problem is that I also need to keep track of the insertion order of duplicates so that it's always the first inserted duplicate that gets retrieved first. Duplicates are just orders that have the same price in this case.

The Java `PriorityQueue` class seems to make no promises regarding the retrieval order of duplicates, so I need some other alternative. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a field or wrap the element with an atomic counter and/or timestamp to record the original order.

Comment: Exactly. Use the constructor that takes a `Comparator`, and make that function compare the counter or timestamp as well as the item id.

Comment: Adding on to using Atomic Counters, it would be e.g. **Initialize**: `final static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();` **Usage**: `counter.getAndIncrement()` would atomically increment each current value by one.